# How can I pass an element as a parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new {from = ? , to = ? , page}))
```

And this is my `Action` method:

```
public ActionResult Index(string from, string to, int? page)
{
}
```

I want to specify the `from` and `to` parameters that comes from a picker which are defined as below:

```
@Html.EditorFor(c => c.LastOrDefault().Date, "MyPickerTemplate")
@Html.EditorFor(c => c.FirstOrDefault().Date, "MyPickerTemplate")
```

How can I send the value of the `EditorFor's` as a parameter to `Url.Action`? I can find them with javaScript like below:

```
var from = document.GetElementByClassName("date")[0].value;
var to = document.GetElementByClassName("date")[1].value;
```

But I don't know **how should I send them as parameter to `Url.Action`**.

Answer (score 1):

```
var from = document.GetElementByClassName("date")[0].value;
var to = document.GetElementByClassName("date")[1].value;
```

Now you have two parameters. You can call ajax function as below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Controller/TheAction", 
    type: "get",
    data: { fromParam: from, toParam: to }
 });
```

Here is the controller,

```
public ActionResult TheAction(DateTime fromParam, DateTime toParam)
{
    // your code.
}
```

EDIT:
You must call ajax from pager button click. For that, do following.

```
<div id="myPager">
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, Page => "")
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#myPager').on('click', 'a', function () {
            var currentPage = $(this);
            // ajax call
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: But I want to send them whit @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new {from = ? , to = ? , page})). How I should relevant my code with this ajax?

Comment: Also I will change the date element from picker and I think this ajax is used only first time since it is get.

Comment: Just did exactly what you said but no luck.

Comment: You need to get two dates in this function before ajax, and `currentPage` would give you `<a>` tag like `<a>1</>`. So you need to extract page number from that. Now define method with necessary parameters like pagenumber, fromParam and toParam. In ajax, send three params.